# To be listed among editors, one has to edit 5 posts... or more than 5?

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, users, list

Incorrect tooltip text is not a big deal, but it might damage the credibility of math-oriented SE sites.

[image: 5edits]

Should be "at least 5 posts" or "more than 4 posts".

Comment: I vote for "at least".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tooltip updated to "at least" to correspond to the actual rule.

With you in the next build.

Thanks for reporting!